# Uniqueness of identity isomorphism between $F_1$ and $F_2$

Tags: universal-property, free-modules

Prove that if $F_1$ and $F_2$ are free modules on the same set $A$, there is a unique isomorphism between $F_1$ and $F_2$ which is the identity map on $A$.

My solution : Let us take the inclusion maps $i_1:A→F_1$ and $i_2:A→F_2$. Then by universal property of modules we have $i_2=f_1*i_1$ and $i_1=f_2*i_2$, where the maps $f_1$ and $f_2$ are assigned by $f_1:F_1→F_2$ and $f_2:F_2→F_1$ and $*$ denotes the composition of two maps. Then from above argument we get $f_2*f_1$ is an identity map in $A$, so $f_1$ is invertible and hence isomorphism.
But how can I show that $f_1$ is the identity only.

Please help me to solve this. I can't proceed further.

Comment: It's not true that $f_1$ (or $f_2$) is the identity map; the modules $F_1$ and $F_2$ might be different sets. What is true is that $f_1$ is the identity map on $A$, i.e., that $f_1$ maps each element of $A$ (not each element of $F_1$) to itself. That conclusion amounts to the equation $f_1\circ i_1=i_2$ that you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you need to use the uniqueness part of the universal property. Let $F$ be the free-module functor from Set to Mod, and $G$ the forgetful functor from Mod to Set; you've so far only used that "for every map $A \to GX$ there is a lift $FA \to X$". You need to use "for every map there is a *unique* lift".